# How to overwrite core files in magento 2

Tags: php, magento-2.0

How to overwrite a core files in magento 2. I need to edit vendor/magento/module_customer/block/account/authorizationlink.php

I have overrided a module_customer by creating custom module. But it shows blank page in both frontend and backend.

Can anyone explain the procedure of overwriting core files in magento2

Comment: Do you need  vendor file override or app/core file ?

Comment: I need to override vendor file

Comment: Bad idea. Try observers before taking that step.